# Is it impossible to get the click table which is dynamically generated?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
    console.log("deleteclick");
});

for (i = 0; i < e.data.length;i++){
       $('#methodTable').append('<tr><td>' + e.data[i].isTejimai + 
               '</td><td>'+ e.data[i].isLossProfCut + '</td><td>' +
            '<button id="' + e.data[i].id + 
            '" class="btn btn-default btn-md delete">' + 
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>' + 
            '</button></td></tr>');
}
```

This code adding `<tr></tr>` to the methodTable dynamically

This made the html like this(debug window output)

```
<button id="6" class="btn btn-default btn-md delete" data-enpassid="__1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</button>
```

It has the class `delete`, so if I click this button it should call the `delete function` but it doesn't work.

If I don't dynamically generate the table, this function works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `.delete` element was added dynamically to the DOM you should attach the click event using the delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** like :

```
$('body').on('click','.delete',function(){
    console.log("deleteclick");
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('body').on('click','.delete',function(){
  console.log("delete click on button "+this.id);
});

for (i = 1; i <= 3;i++){
  $('#methodTable').append('<tr><td>Column 1 </td><td>Column 2 </td><td>' +
    ' <button id="id_'+i+'" class="btn btn-default btn-md delete">' + 
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>' + 
    '</button></td></tr>');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id='methodTable'></table>
```

Comment: I seeee!! in my first source code, $(".delete").on definition is called before .delete object made.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
$('.delete').on('click',function() {
    //your operations 
});
```

Use the following :

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    //your operations
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, When you want bind any event to a particular element then that element should be present before you bind that event(even the same element as previous, you create newly).

That's why JavaScript frameworks like **AngularJs** are so famous, to achieve the same you want.